# How do I build an Index in Nhibernate.Search (Lucene.Net)?

Tags: lucene.net, nhibernate.search

I'm trying to add a search field to my web site (ASP.NET MVC 2) and was told it'd be a good idea to use Nhibernate.Search, seeing that I was already using Nhibernate in the rest of the project.

Anyway, I followed a coulpe tutorials, namely [this one](http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/lucene-net-and-nhibernate-search-on-medium-trust), and some questions and answeres on this site, but in the end, it does not build an index, and searches come empty.

I know this question might be a bit vague, but it seems strange that nothing works even after I've done everything I was told.

Well, almost everything. At some point, in one of the tutorials, it tells me to type:

```
using (IFullTextSession s = Search.CreateFullTextSession(sf.OpenSession(new SearchInterceptor()))) {

        QueryParser qp = new QueryParser("id", new StopAnalyzer());

        IQuery NHQuery = s.CreateFullTextQuery(qp.Parse("Summary:series"), typeof(Book));

        IList result = NHQuery.List();

        Debug.Assert(result.Count == 2);
}
```

wich does not work because SearchInterceptor does not exist anywhere...

Am I missing something here?
Is there a way to better write the search queries?
In which part of my application does it build the index?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried something like:

```
public bool LuceneIndexAllVideos()
    {
        var s = NHibernate.Search.Search.CreateFullTextSession(Session);

        foreach (Video video in Videos)
        {
            s.Index(video);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

But is slow, but it seems to work nice...
See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989125/lucene-net-nhibernate-updating-lucene-index-from-existing-data